# Juicer - Limit number of posts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Is there a way to limit the number of posts being displayed, using the [react-juicer-feed component](https://github.com/juicer-io/react-juicer-feed)?

```
import { Feed } from 'react-juicer-feed';

const MyFeed = () => {
  return (
    <Feed
      feedId="<feed-id>"
      perPage={3}
    />
  );
};
```

Does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like that library actually implements the `data-per` attribute [as per documentation](https://help.juicer.io/hc/en-us/articles/360039929412-Code-customizations-for-date-range-feed-style-spacing-filtering-and-more)

As a matter of fact that repo contains a pretty basic embedding of the library so you could fork it, edit the `render()` function in [this file](https://github.com/juicer-io/react-juicer-feed/blob/master/src/juicer_feed.js#L30)
yourself to look like this:

```
[...]
render() {
    return (
      <ul className='juicer-feed' data-feed-id={this.props.feedId} data-per={this.props.dataPer} />
    );
  }
[...]
```

Then

```
import { Feed } from 'react-juicer-feed';

const MyFeed = () => {
  return (
    <Feed
      feedId="<feed-id>"
      dataPer={3}
    />
  );
};
```

and add that fork to your project. Either that or embed the script yourself entirely on your own and add the data attribute.